# Echo item from stdClass object from shipment tracking response

Tags: php, aramex

I am trying to track shipments from the Aramex API. The following result is the response I got from the request sent to track shipment number 59398114932:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [Transaction] => stdClass Object
        (
            [Reference1] => 
            [Reference2] => 
            [Reference3] => 
            [Reference4] => 
            [Reference5] => 
        )

    [Notifications] => stdClass Object
        (
        )

    [HasErrors] => 
    [TrackingResults] => stdClass Object
        (
            [KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [Key] => 59398114932
                    [Value] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [TrackingResult] => stdClass Object
                                (
                                    [WaybillNumber] => 59398114932
                                    [UpdateCode] => SH005
                                    [UpdateDescription] => Delivered
                                    [UpdateDateTime] => 2016-09-26T14:45:00
                                    [UpdateLocation] => new york
                                    [Comments] => joe
                                    [ProblemCode] => 
                                )
                        )
                )
        )
)
```

But what I actually need is only the `[UpdateDescription]` from the above response in order to know when the shipment is delivered. How can I echo it?

Here is the request I sent:

```
$auth_call = $soapClient->TrackShipments($params);
```

The shipment number is sent by the `$params` array.

Comment: what about this ? `<?php
$description = $auth_call->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY->Value->TrackingResult->UpdateDescription;
echo $description;
?>`

Comment: `echo $response->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY->Value->TrackingResult->UpdateDescription;`

Comment: @Noman, looks fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you have the array of Object, you need to use `->` for each depth of the array. Let your response array object is `$response`.

```
echo $response->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingR‌​esultmFAkxlpY->Value‌​->TrackingResult->Up‌​dateDescription;
```

There is nothing complex, just simple. Use the `->` sign for the each array depth of this array object.

Comment: DID you replace the `$response` with your array object??

Answer (score 0):

If you only need the Update Description, then this should do it:

```
echo $your_object->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTrackingResultmFAkxlpY->Value->TrackingResult->UpdateDescription;
```

Comment: no output from echoing

Comment: Have you replaced $your_object to the real name of the response object?

Comment: yes replaced it with $auth_call

Comment: how did you print the response that you have shown above?

Comment: $auth_call = $soapClient->TrackShipments($params);
  print_r($soapClient->TrackShipments($params));

  echo $auth_call->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTracking‌​ResultmFAkxlpY->Valu‌​e->TrackingResult->U‌​pdateDescription;

Comment: any thing i need to change ?

Comment: Hmmm. Can you store in a variable and use print_r to print? Like this: $auth_call = $soapClient->TrackShipments($params); print_r($soapClient->TrackShipments($params)); $update_description = $auth_call->TrackingResults->KeyValueOfstringArrayOfTracking‌​‌​ResultmFAkxlpY->Va‌​lu‌​e->TrackingResul‌​t;

(Note: Only until TrackingResult so that we can check its structure and content)